# Zimbra: Run Network Edition and Open Source together

Tags: email, exchange, zimbra

A customer wants to have approximately 15% of users on Zimbra Network Edition (paid version) and balance on the open source edition. Is this possible? If so what are the steps we need to take?

I have heard of solutions where a few users are on Exchange and balance on the Linux Server running Postfix. Is such a similar arrangement possible with Zimbra

Answer (score 0):

with a separated directory server, you can have two zimbra hosts, one running NE and another OSE, both authenticating to the central directory. You will require at least two servers of course.

Comment: Thanks. But your comment makes no sense. What directory are you talking about?

Comment: No sense? How many directory servers can you think of? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_service